# get current category ID in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get category ID of the current archive displayed.

```
<select id="post-select">
  <?php
    $posts = get_posts(array(
      'category' => get_query_var('cat'),
      'numberposts' => -1
    ));
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
      echo '<option value="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . $post->post_title . '</option>';
    }
  ?>
</select>

<script>
  document.getElementById("post-select").addEventListener("change", function() {
    window.location = this.value;
  });
</script>
```

But the posts of all categories are displayed

Comment: Where do you have write this code? in category archive ? If you add this code in category archive, then it should return posts from that specific category only. Nb: ```category.php``` is the category archive template.

Comment: This code is write in the single.php , at the top of the page

Comment: single.php is used for single post pages. So what is you mean by "current archive" when you staying in single.php?